# Editing list of lists in python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to edit a list of lists by

```
s[0][0]=1
```

but instead of just the first number in the first row changing to 1, the first number in all the rows are changing to 1.

I was first taught python using 2.7, but the class I'm taking now requires 3.4. Was there a change in syntax between the two versions? Otherwise, what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect you created your lists by multiplication: [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178)

Comment: Did you use multiplication to build your list of lists?

Comment: Most importantly, you created references to *the same list object* rather than new lists. You'll have to show us *how* you created those lists for us to be able to help any further.

Comment: I did use multiplication to create my list. Thank you!

Comment: Aside: when asking a question, you should create a [self-contained working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the problem; while multiplication was a reasonable guess, there are other ways you could have produced the same effect (multiple references to a single list).